# Wordpress post image not from media library

Tags: node.js, wordpress, media

Is it possible to create post with image not from a media library ? I have tons of images on azure blob storage and I don't want upload this images to wp with new post. Instead I prefer to specify somehow image link. I didn't saw in docs such possibility. I am using next api  - [NodeJs client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wordpress) &  [rest api](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/). Thanks.

Comment: I can suggest you are a workaround. Create a custom fields where you store your url to azure and then set this image as post thumbail on "save_post" hook or just use this when displaying the post and not the thumbail :))

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible to host your images and media externally without uploading those to your WordPress instance.

I guess this Plugin does exactly what you need (adds images to your media library, but you do not have to upload or host them to my understanding):

https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/external-media-upload/

If not, there is a bunch of other Plugins therefore you do not even have to implement a solution like this yourself. MANY WordPress websites are using either a CDN or even an external storage for media.